# How to close a word document

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, vb6

When I run this application, the document opens fine but it doesn't close and leaves the document open. How can I close the word doc properly?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim AppWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Dim WordDoc = CreateObject("Word.Document")
    Dim filename As String
    Dim result As String

    filename = "C:\Users\Business\Desktop\Test.docx"

    WordDoc = AppWord.Documents.Open(filename)
    txtFileContents.Text = WordDoc.Content.Text
    WordDoc.Close()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps, you want to close the Word app at the end? Try this:

```
AppWord.Quit
```

Answer (score -1):

use the shell function to close it (taskkill)